# How to add GWT Wrappers for Google APIs to GWT Designer's Palette?

Tags: gwt-designer

I'm using GWT Designer to build a site.
I use the Google Visualization API and would like to be able to place Pie Charts, Timelines, etc in my Panels.

Anyone know how to add GWT libs for Google APIs to the GWT Designer Palette?

Cheers,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only valid GWT widgets and panels may be added to the palette, so you would need to wrap those APIs into widgets and expose appropriate JavaBean APIs for them.